# Setting Layout.fillHeight: true make rectangle invisible In Qt Quick 2

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying to create a basic layout for my application. I want it to look like this [image: this]. This is my set up so far.

## main.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("basic layout")

    ColumnLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        spacing: 0

        Header {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 50
        }

        Body {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }

        Footer {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            height: 30
        }
    }
}
```

## Header.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Rectangle {
    color: "red"
}
```

## Footer.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Rectangle {
    color: "blue"
}
```

## Body.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent

        Rectangle {
            color: "red"

            width: 100
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "green"

            width: 400
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "blue"

            width: 400
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }

        Rectangle {
            color: "black"

            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
    }
}
```

When it's ran In the, the `Body` section I get is nothing but white space. [image: This what i get] Rectangles are visible when i give them a size manually. I tried adding `anchors.fill: parent` to `Item` level in `Body.qml`. Still result is the same. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. I just copied your code, run it, and it looks (almost) as in the first picture of yours.

Comment: I also cannot reproduce your issue. Working for me on 5.9.1

Comment: Could this be a issue with my operating system? I'm using Lubuntu. Qt version 5.9.2

Comment: Try to log the `width`, `height`, `x` and `y` of your `Rectangle`s. Maybe this gives valuable information.

Comment: Working well for me too.

Comment: Working as expected on Ubuntu 16.04, Qt 5.5.1 (using QtQuick 2.5, Controls 1.4, Layouts 1.2).

Answer (score 1):

You have to set rectangle's width in the RowLayout using

```
Layout.preferredWidth: 400
```

instead of

```
 width: 400
```